# What is the opposite movement of "go into the shade of the wall": "go into the sunny area"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

> **[shade](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/shade_1?q=shade)**: [uncountable] an area that is dark and cool under or behind something,
>   for example a tree or building, because the sun’s light does not get
>   to it
>
> **shade of something** The shade of the pine tree provided some
>   protection from the sun.
>
> **in the shade** The temperature can reach 40°C in the shade.
>
> **in the shade of something** We sat down in the shade of the wall.
>
> **in shade** These plants grow well in sun or shade.
>
> **under the shade of something** Two cows were sleeping under the shade
>   of some trees.
>
> The trees provide shade for the animals in the summer.

---

So, we say "**Please go into the shade of the wall**" and what is its opposite movement "**Please go into the sunny area**"?

Comment: We say _in the shade_ and _in the sun_. It isn't necessary to state what is  causing the shade unless you particularly need to do so.

Comment: @KateBunting, interesting. So, "sit in the sun" & "sit in the shade" are opposite, aren't they?

Comment: Yes, they are opposites.